# Configure XSD file path in SSIS 2008

Tags: ssis

I have created a package for extracting data from XML file to SQL server table. I have configured XML File path in dtsConfig file while I am unable to configure XSD file path. How will we configure XSD file path ?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the XSD file path in SSIS configuration as @gannaway explained. But, you have a better option to dynamically set the value of the connection to your `.xsc` file:

1. You need to create a string variable that will hold your `.xsd` address.
2. Then click on dataflow and go to `Expressions` on the `Properties`.
3. select xmlsource.xmlschemadeifination propery from the dropdown and assign that variable to the property.
4. Now go inside the configuration file and set the XSD file path location to the variable.

For more info on working with XML and XSD go to:  http://sqlbisam.blogspot.com/2013/11/xml-task-in-ssis.html

Answer (score 1):

The steps below assume you know how to navigate to the **Package Configuration Wizard** to create a dtsConfig file.

- In the **Package Configuration Wizard** on the **Select Properties to Export** page, find the *Data Flow* that contains your *XML Source* under the *Executables* folder
- Expand the `Data Flow`
- Expand the `Properties` folder
- Find the **XMLSchemaDefinition** property of your *XML Source*.  It will be in the format `[XMLSourceName].[XMLSchemaDefinition]`.  If the name of your *XML Source* was **MyXMLSource** then it would be `[MyXMLSource].[XMLSchemaDefinition]`.
- Check the checkbox next to it to include it in your dtsConfig file
- Click Next and then Finish to export your dtsConfig file

Below is a sample dtsConfig that was generated from the **Package Configuration Wizard**.  Here I had a *Data Flow* named `testDF`, an XML Source named `MyXMLSource`, and my XSD path was `C:\temp\myXsd.xsd`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DTSConfiguration>
  <DTSConfigurationHeading>
    <DTSConfigurationFileInfo GeneratedBy="abc123" GeneratedFromPackageName="Package" GeneratedFromPackageID="{3AA21177-18D7-4EBF-8C79-9300F7E03090}" GeneratedDate="12/13/2013 11:21:33 PM"/>
  </DTSConfigurationHeading>

  <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package\testDF.Properties[[MyXMLSource].[XMLSchemaDefinition]]" ValueType="String">
    <ConfiguredValue>C:\temp\myXsd.xsd</ConfiguredValue>
  </Configuration>

</DTSConfiguration>
```